# Jquery ajaxForm clear form after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I need the form to be cleared after the form has been submitted. TIA

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#msgform').ajaxForm(function (data, textStatus) {
$("#msgresults").show();
$('#msgresults').append(data);
});
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach a .submit() listener in which you set the contents of whatever form elements.

Somewhat like

```
$('#msgform').submit(function () {
  $(this).children('input[type=text]').val('');
});
```

Comment: can you please post the entire code. I dont know where to insert your code snippet into my code. Thanks.

Comment: You can just attach it anywhere, really. It's an event listener, so it'll be triggered when you submit the form.

Your solution of just tacking it in the callback works just as well, though.

Answer (score 6):

You could try this:

```
$('#msgform')[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct code. I found a solution to clear the textarea field with the id of 'msgtextarea'

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('#msgform').ajaxForm(function (data, textStatus) {
            $("#msgresults").show();
            $('#msgresults').append(data);
            $("#msgtextarea").val("")
      });
  }); 
</script>
```